# Which hardware timer is used for hr timers in linux?

Tags: linux, timer, linux-kernel, kernel

The kernel timers are based on the systick HW timer (systick HW timer block or some other timer) with a resolution of 1 jiffy. In case of hr timers (high resolution timers) the resolution is 1 ns. Which hardware timer is used for the operation of hr timers to get 1 ns resolution? I think the hardware timer used for hr timers vary from platform to platform. Any typical example is fine for me. Also, could you point in code where exactly we declare that hr timers use that particular hardware timer?

Comment: Take a look https://export.writer.zoho.com/public/rreginelli/Chapter-5---High-Resolution-Timers-Final1/fullpage

Comment: @Satish That has nothing to do with the question.

Answer (score 4):

The resolution is just labelled as 1 ns; the actual resolution depends on the hardware.

High-resolution timers use a *clock events device*, which is registered by [clockevents_register_device](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=clockevents_register_device).

On x86, this is typically the per-CPU local APIC timer.

Comment: On my PC timeouts under 1 ms are missed, and on my embedded board (C.H.I.P.) the minimum right value is 10ms. How can I get the real HR timer resolution? Thank you

Comment: @AntonioPetricca You have to look at the respective clock event driver, and the documentation of its hardware.

Comment: Thank you, but could you tell me how to check which driver my system uses?

Comment: @AntonioPetricca You should start with the source code of your system, and its kernel configuration. And if that does not help, ask a new question.

Comment: I went deeper in kernel log and I discovered that for C.H.I.P. board the clock source is the internal h/w timer with a resolution of 5 ms, not 10 ms as I previously stated, but this seems to be the answer to my question. Thank you :)